# What alternative approach could be used in C# to avoid method returning `object` type?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I know that the method is returning `List<string>` at the moment. But in some (which occur quite frequently in our application) scenarios, it returns List having **only one** string.

So eventually it would return either `string` or `List<string>`.

Since it's unpredictable what it'll return at run time, at present it's return type is kept as `object`.

What alternative approach could be used to avoid method returning `object`?

EDIT:
I would like to have answer to the question **What alternative approach could be used to avoid method returning `object`?** ; without considering the scenario I described. List is enough here.

Comment: Why not always return List<string>, even when there is just one element? Having the clients check for the length of the list seems a much smaller hassle than having them cast to the proper type.

Comment: I had done the same thing (List<string>. But consumers of API complain that why to iterate over the list when it's going to have only one string at a time!! (It's irritating question to me.) So I asked the question to know if experts here have some better solution.

Comment: @CSharpLearner tell them to call `.Single()` if they expect exactly one result.

Comment: Or provide a second method which always returns one result.  Though I much prefer telling them to call `.Single()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

why return a `string`? a `List<string>` with a single `string` in it is *perfectly* well defined... use that! An ambiguous API is silly here.

Another option might be `IEnumerable<string>`, but... meh, just return the list with a single `string`!

Comment: Edited the question and added comment.  I would like to have answer to the question What alternative approach could be used to avoid method returning object? ; without considering the scenario I described. List is enough here.

Comment: @CSharpLearner - there is *deliberately* not a metaphor for that, because frankly it isn't a great idea to have an API that returns such varying results. Did you note my point about `.Single()` ?

Comment: yes, I read your comment about `.Single`. And given +1 too for that.

Answer (score 3):

Return a List that contains one or more string elements, and process the list as a list regardless of the number of elements it contains.

Answer (score 2):

There is no problem to have a List with one and more and even with no string(empty list).
Why you want to have string when there is only one element in the List. 
Just keep the API more clear.

Answer (score 1):

I dont see the the problem of returning `List<string>` even the `List` contain only one element. But if you really want your method to behave differently with one string value, you could do

```
public List<string> GetStrList(out string val)
{
//set str = string.Empty; when value is more than one

//set str = whateverstring when value is only one
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, does this method perhaps call 2 different methods inside its body, one returning a `string` and one returning a `List<string>`? If so, maybe you could change your method to return an `IEnumerable<string>`, and change the `return GetSingleString();` statement to [`yield return`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)`GetSingleString();`

Or you could add it to a list with a single element and return the list, like some of the other answers suggest here